# How many spaces are there?

Tags: code-golf, string, counting, whitespace

Your task is to input a string, and output the number of spaces in the string.

This is code-golf, so least number of bytes win. Your

## Test Cases

Double quotes are not part of the test cases.

```
"test" => 0
"Hello, World!" => 1
"C O D E G O L F" => 7
"      " => 6
```

Comment: What characters can be in the string? Just printable ASCII, or can there be unicode characters, tabs, newlines etc?

Comment: What is considered a space? Only 32@ASCII or other whitespace characters too?

Comment: @JoKing Just printable ASCII if you want.

Comment: @JoKing It is probably not a duplicate since - You don't have to input the character you need to find, which allows for cool solutions for example: Retina, 1 byte ` `.(Not created for it though)

Comment: I don't think having one of the parameters hard-coded changes the challenge enough to not make it a dupe

Comment: @JoKing But I don't think there's a lot of challenge which have an 1-byte Retina solution. Also, space are special for a lot of languages, see APL answer, 05AB1E answer and so much more.

Comment: @JoKing I won't argue, though. This is my first closed challenge!

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
+/=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X1vf9n/ao7YJj3r7HvVN9fR/1NV8aL3xo7aJQF5wkDOQDPHwDP6fpl6SWlyizpWm7pGak5OvoxCeX5SToggScFbwV3BRcFVwB9I@Cm4gIQUwUAcA)

`+/` sum the mask where `=` equal to the prototypical element of that element, which is space for characters.

Comment: Cool.  Is the idea of a prototypical element Dyalog specific?

Comment: @Jonah It is typical (!) of APL, although some new hobby implementations do not implement this. E.g. in APL2, APLX, and Dyalog is `' ' '   '(0 0 ' ')` the prototype of `'a' 'abc'(1 2 'c')`

Comment: Interesting.  Golang has the idea of a type's "zero value", but I've never come across anything analogous in J.

Comment: @Jonah While neat, it does cause various issues, like needing to call `f each` once on empty arrays to determine the prototype and inability to get a prototype from certain elements (e.g. objects), so Iverson and Hui decided J would only do specific prototypes for simple arrays, while all boxes would give `a:`, so `' '={.0$'hello'` and `0={.0$1 2 3` and `a:={.0$'hello';1 2 3`

Comment: ah right!  that’s where i’d seen it in J!   thanks @Adám

Answer (score 4):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 93 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_top][S N
S _Duplicate_top][T N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S S S T    S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate_top][N
T   S T N
_If_0_jump_to_label_DONE][S S S T   S T T   S N
_Push_22][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_jump_to_label_SPACE][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_SPACE][S S S T    N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_DONE][S N
N
_Discard_top][T N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace inputs one character at a time, the input should contain a trailing newline so it knows when to stop reading characters and the input is done.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LY3BCcAwDAPf8hTaoROlJZD8CjF0g747Yxdx5TRgS/hs4at1r@MsR40gaabmFBgIQFBODanpsJ8tmKKYZZRzlYSLIF2CCG99UFWoj66T9364cT4fyMHLbh8) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

An appropriate language for the challenge I guess. PS: The program itself contains 44 spaces.

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer counter = 0
Start LOOP:
  Character c = STDIN as character
  If(c == ' '):
    Call function SPACE
  Else-if(c == '\n'):
    Call function DONE
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function SPACE:
  counter = counter + 1
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function DONE:
  Print counter as integer to STDOUT
```

Comment: The irony of using whitespaces to find whitespaces!

Comment: Using Whitespace for this challenge is like using Unreadable for Tex Quotes.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>3</strike> 2 bytes

```
ð¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IZDi/7/d1bwV3BRcFVwB9I@Cm4A)

Simple explanation:

```
 ð  Pushes ' ' space character onto stack
  ¢ Counts the spaces in the input string
```

Found the 'ð' Command which saves 1 Byte for pushing a space.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
1#.' '=]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX11BXUbWP/a3JxpSZn5AOlbBXSFNRLUotL1CEihhARj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURaiUOUTKWcFfwUXBVcEdSPsouEElzSCSCmCg/h8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 26 bytes

```php
<?=count_chars($argn)[32];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Ob80ryQ@OSOxqFhDJbEoPU8z2tgo1vp/anJGvoJSTJ6S9f@S1OISLo/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUuZwV/BRcFVwV3IO2j4MalAAb/8gtKMvPziv/rugEA)

Comment: That was quick. What, there's a built-in in PHP called "count_chars"? Wow!

Comment: @TwilightSparkle Probably the simplest challenge I have ever seen :P I will be surprised if this isn't already a duplicate. `substr_count` can also be used to count, but it will be 27 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uDSpuKQoPjm/NK9EQyWxKD1PR11BXdP6f2pyRr6CUkyekvX/ktTiEi6P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFLmcFfwUXBVcFdyDto@DGpQAG//ILSjLz84r/67oBAA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: I will be surprised if this isn't a duplicate... too. But I searched a bit and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 20 bytes

I really hope this is not optimal

```cs
a=>a.Count(b=>b==32)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrqOQmVdip@CmYPs/0dYuUc85vzSvRCPJ1i7J1tbYSPO/NVcAUFmJhpuGUolCqkKxQomSpqb1fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

-2 byte thanks to ngn

```
+/^:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NSls/zup/mrqGUklqcYmStYKSR2pOTr6OQnh@UU6KIkjAWcFfwUXBVcEdSPsouIGEFMBASfM/AA)

Comment: `" "` -> `32`­­

Comment: in k4 monadic `^` compares with null, which is `" "` for chars, so the solution could be `+/^:`

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
ċ⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I96PGbf///3dW8FdwUXBVcAfSPgpuAA)

Literally `ċ` count `⁶` spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 7 bytes

```perl
$_=y; ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X6wfp1SjpKelr59u/V8l3rbSWsH6/3@lktTiEiUFWzsFAy4lj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURbCgIZeSs4K/gouCq4I7kPZRcAMLm3MpKYABmGf2L7@gJDM/r/i/bk4BAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 18 bytes

```
($args-eq32).count
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HY7LCgIxDEX3/YpridJCFR@gIAiCz4Xg0qWMWnQxWO2MKIzz7fU62STnXELyCG8fi5vP8yQnzFAlI1m8Fl3/HA1t7xxe9zLVShld@qLUDn3rCFsuBIdDiPmlRTto7AJ7LLHChn2HNf2k8WiKOLb4ol0pQDIH@fCgHP8UOXXAD@YZUYthxhcY2CmkirVWdfoB).

Expects input via [splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

Answer (score 1):

### CJam (5 bytes)

```
q' e=
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q'%20e%3D&input=This%20is%20a%20test)

```
qS/,(
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qS%2F%2C(&input=This%20is%20a%20test)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 27 bytes

```java
s->s.split(" ",-1).length-1
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZU@xTsMwEN37FQ8vtZXGUlcqWKCFAcrQgQEYjGNaF9eJcpdKCPXbg2PCUOHhrHvv3b13e3M05b767G0wRHg0Pn5PAB/ZtR/GOqyHNgOwcsOtj1uQWiTwNEmF2LC3WCPiqqfymjQ1wbMUELNyrnRwccu7ct4vBnXTvYekHoeOta9wSI7j3pc3GPVrx47SjqGK7PWH3LsQ6hme6zZUF@fUDZ5wiyXu0v@A1TmJ/MS/3DlCloyn@dh0PIbYfBG7g6471k0iOUQ5FdMiSwrxKi4hiqitzIC2O9OSVGr0OPU/)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                         // Method with String as parameter and integer return-type
  s.split(" ",              //  Split the input on spaces
              -1)           //  While retaining empty strings as items
                 .length    //  Get the amount of items in the array
                        -1  //  And subtract 1
```

Using the `count()` builtin with a filter for spaces would be 2 bytes longer (or 1 if the input is guaranteed to not contain tabs/newlines/other characters below spaces - in which case the `==32` can be `<33`):

```java
s->s.filter(c->c==32).count()
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZZA9T8MwEED3/orDS22FeICNKl34lqAMHRgog3Hc4uDYUXyuhFB/e7i4YajwcLbvnu@e3Ki9Kpv6a9BOxQjPyvqfGYD1aPqt0gZW4xXABb8DzRvCZULrZMTeqFY@elznE0SxIPIwoxBRodWwAg/VEMtllFvrqCHX5VJX1eWFkDokj1wMi5Hv0ocjfnq2D7aGlkQ4dbZ@9/YOShwt0ETkbIwsT/vLPBjnwjm8ht7VZ6ela3iBG7iFe9qf4O60CHmxf@ZZISNHBfqPLuEksf6OaFoZEsqOiug8n7N5kZGCbdgVsMJLzXNC6k/VRy7ENOMw/AI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
{∋Ṣ}ᶜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv/pRR/fDnYtqH26b8/9/tFJJanGJko6SR2pOTr6OQnh@UU6KIpDvrOCv4KLgquAOpH0U3IAiCmCgFAsA)

```
{  }ᶜ    The output is the number of ways in which
 ∋       an element of the input can be chosen
  Ṣ      such that the element is a space.
```

Alternatively,

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ṇ₁l-₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@HO9kdNjTm6QOL//2ilktTiEiUdJY/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFEUg31nBX8FFwVXBHUj7KLgBRRTAQCkWAA)

```
  l      The length of
ṇ₁       the input split on spaces
   -₁    minus one is the output.
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) and template literals!

```js
s=>s.split` `.length-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy9CsJAEIT7e4o1VQLJgXWIjUYtBEsLERIud/lhuQ3Z1UZ89jNGMs3MfAwz1K@azdSPknlqbHBF4GLHmkfspYJKo/WtdNk2oBUQy8JQwF3BrOhXo/SfzxaRUrjRhM1mhXu4wgFKOM1@geOKYVGkHrlSy6V2NJW16WL39EZ68jEn72VryDOh1Uht7Gaa5OqT5OEL)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 21 bytes

```python
lambda s:s.count(' ')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlgvOb80r0RDXUFd839BUSaQmaahnpefl6quqckFFwDyFYoLEpNRRXPzi1IVSjIS8xSQ5f8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Yawn!

```
èS
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=6FM&input=InRlc3Qi)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 15 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.count' '}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvOb80r0RdQb32f4FCWrR6Xn5eqnosF5gNZCoUFyQmwwVy84tSFUoyEvMUkKT@AwA)

Uhmmm...

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 9 bytes

```
Count@" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zm/NK/EQUlB6X9AUWZeSbRSjJKSjrIOmFJS0LVTUNJJc3DOSCxKTC5JLSp2UI5V03eo5lIqSS0uUdLhUvJIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVEECTgr@Cu4KLgquANpHwU3kJACGChx1f4HAA)

Takes a list of characters as input.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
gÅ =£
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/9cKuC7aHF//9Hq5eo66inAnExEJeox3JFqysAWZgYJOMBVZsDxflArANVEQ7lF0HlUoBYEazLGarCH0q7QGlXKO2OJu8Dpd3UYwE)

**Explanation:**

```python
g      # Filter the (implicit) input-list
 Å     #  Using the following two commands:
   =   #  Equals a space
    £  #  Then pop this filtered list and get its length for the amount of spaces
       # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Or alternatively: `mÅ =Σ` ([Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/3cKuC7bnF//9Hq5eo66inAnExEJeox3JFqysAWZgYJOMBVZsDxflArANVEQ7lF0HlUoBYEazLGarCH0q7QGlXKO2OJu8Dpd3UYwE)), which is similar but uses a map & sum instead of filter & length.